# XML parsing with unique tags for sub element

Tags: python, pandas, elementtree

I have below xml data

```
xml_data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <DATA VERSION="1">
        <transaction>
            <receiptNo>123</receiptNo>
            <item>
                <code>163</code>
                <price>1100</price>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <items>
                    <item>
                        <code>145</code>
                        <price>1200</price>
                        <qty>1</qty>
                        <items>
                            <item>
                                <code>174</code>
                                <price>0</price>
                                <qty>1</qty>
                            </item>
                            <item>
                                <code>172</code>
                                <price>400</price>
                                <qty>1</qty>
                            </item>
                        </items>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <code>363</code>
                        <price>500</price>
                        <qty>1</qty>
                    </item>
                </items>
            </item>
            <item>
                <code>060</code>
                <price>900</price>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <items>
                    <item>
                        <code>600</code>
                        <price>0</price>
                        <qty>1</qty>
                    </item>
                </items>
            </item>
        </transaction>
    </DATA>
"""
```

I have successfully parsed it using the below code

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)

cols = ['receiptNo','code','price','qty','item_id']
df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

for trx in root.iter('transaction'):
    receiptNo = trx.find('receiptNo').text

    item_id = 0

    for it in trx.iter('item'):
        code = it.find('code').text
        price = it.find('price').text
        qty = it.find('qty').text

        item_id += 1    

        df_xml = df_xml.append(pd.Series([receiptNo,code,price,qty,item_id],
                                         index=cols),ignore_index=True)
```

And I get the output as below

```
+---+-----------+------+-------+-----+---------+
|   | receiptNo | code | price | qty | item_id |
+---+-----------+------+-------+-----+---------+
| 0 |       123 |  163 |  1100 |   1 |       1 |
| 1 |       123 |  145 |  1200 |   1 |       2 |
| 2 |       123 |  174 |     0 |   1 |       3 |
| 3 |       123 |  172 |   400 |   1 |       4 |
| 4 |       123 |  363 |   500 |   1 |       5 |
| 5 |       123 |  060 |   900 |   1 |       6 |
| 6 |       123 |  600 |     0 |   1 |       7 |
+---+-----------+------+-------+-----+---------+
```

my question is on the `item_id` column. what I get is a running sequence of numbers.

I do not want a running sequence number. Instead, each sub item should have it's own running number within it's parents node.

key explanation points,

1. Item code `163` & `060` are directly under `<transaction>` tag.
   Hence, each should get 1 & 2 respectively.(1st Layer) `item_id` column.
2. Item code `145` & `600` are the first child of their respective
   parents node. hence, both should get 1 in the `layer_2` column.
3. item code `174` & `172` are under `145`. these are the grand
   children alias the the 3rd layer. so it should get 1 & 2
   respectively in `layer_3` column.

My desired output is as below

```
+---+-----------+------+-------+-----+---------+---------+---------+
|   | receiptNo | code | price | qty | item_id | layer_2 | layer_3 |
+---+-----------+------+-------+-----+---------+---------+---------+
| 0 |       123 |  163 |  1100 |   1 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| 1 |       123 |  145 |  1200 |   1 |       1 |       1 |       0 |
| 2 |       123 |  174 |     0 |   1 |       1 |       1 |       1 |
| 3 |       123 |  172 |   400 |   1 |       1 |       1 |       2 |
| 4 |       123 |  363 |   500 |   1 |       1 |       2 |       0 |
| 5 |       123 |   60 |   900 |   1 |       2 |       0 |       0 |
| 6 |       123 |  600 |     0 |   1 |       2 |       1 |       0 |
+---+-----------+------+-------+-----+---------+---------+---------+
```

what I think the issue is, when I run `trx.iter('item')`, all the tags with `<item>` are pulled together & given the same sequence. irrespective whether these are under `<items>` tags (plural with 's').

please guide me how to solve this.